# Error within Trigger: System.FinalException: Record is read-only

Tags: apex, trigger, customer-community

Once a custom record is created by a Community user on the Napili Community, **Account** lookup field of that record should be populated from *UserID(CreatedBy) >> ContactId >> AccountID*. I am trying to update a Lookup field of a record after its creation using a trigger.

```
trigger setAccountLookup on Kindle__c (after insert) {
Kindle__c[] resList = new Kindle__c[] {};
   for (Kindle__c res : Trigger.new){
       res.Account__c = res.CreatedBy.Contact.AccountId;
       resList.add(res);
   }
   update resList;
}
```

> ERROR:
>   setAccountLookup: execution of AfterInsert caused by: System.FinalException: Record is read-only Trigger.setAccountLookup: line 4, column 1

Am I missing something or doing it in the wrong way?

Comment: Please refer this post as well: [Trigger After Insert Error](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/14950/exeception-on-after-insert-record-is-read-only)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Apex Developer Guide` clearly recommends you perform field updates in a **`before`** context:

> ## [Triggers](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers.htm)
>
> ...
>
> There are two types of triggers:
>
> - *Before triggers* are used to update or validate record values before they’re saved to the database.
> - *After triggers* are used to access field values that are set by the system (such as a record's Id or LastModifiedDate field), and to affect changes in other records, such as logging into an audit table or firing asynchronous events with a queue. The records that fire the after trigger are read-only.

Note, however, that **[you cannot access parent fields of trigger context records](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/120577/2995)**. You must query for them. Since you are firing this logic on the `insert` event, you can assume `CreatedById` will correspond with the running user, so you should be able to query for just the running user.

```
User runningUser = [SELECT Contact.AccountId FROM User WHERE Id = :UserInfo.getUserId()];
for (MyObject__c record : trigger.new)
{
    record.Account__c = runningUser.Contact.AccountId;
}
```

Comment: To be pedantic, this logic is not strictly applicable, because administrators can now [enable create audit fields](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000213290&language=en_US&type=1) without intervention from support. ☺

Comment: Yes I considered that scenario, but it doesn't seem especially relevant here. Also somewhat peripheral to the main problem.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Sounds good. I might not be able to follow you guys on what you discussed in the above comments, but, I understood what I need to do to make my use-case work. Its good to see you both commenting on my question :)